# Showing posts according to the level of authority in mysql

Tags: mysql

"user" table columns names are "id", "username", "name_surname", "password".
"friends" table columns names are "user_id", "friends", "requests", "bans".
"wall" table columns names are "id", "post", "access", "date", "owner_id", "poster_id".

When a user access his accound page, he is writing "what's on his mind" like facebook and he can choose who can read the post. But when he want to read wall's posts, he must not read all posts. He only able to read if his id is located poster's friends column.

For example, my id is 3, poster id is 5 and friends field holds values as jason data.
In "user" table, id=>3, username=>user1, name=>John, password=>1234
In "friends" table, user_id=>5, friends=>[1,2,3,4,7,8], requests=>[11,12,13], bans=>[31,32,33]
In "wall" table, id=>1, posts=>Here what I think, access=>friends_only, date=>2013-04-25 19:23:00, owner_id=>7, poster_id=5

In accordance with the above information, I am, as id=3, a firend of id=5 user, so I can read wall posts which id=1. In the all stomachache, I did not manage to write sql query. This is my absurd query.

```
"SELECT w.*, u.* FROM wall AS w"
    . " LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.id=w.poster_id"
    . " WHERE w.access='everybody'"
    . " OR (SELECT * FROM wall WHERE w.access='friends_only'"
    . " IN (SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friends contains 3) )"
    . " ORDER BY w.id DESC LIMIT 0,5"
```

Please could you help me writing the correct query?
Kind regards.

Comment: It would be much better to have a different row for each friend instead of having a JSON array. Your friends table would be like: user_id, friend_id, requests, bans

Comment: Too late now. All friendship system and others based on this logic. :)

Comment: Why not have a many to many table? Are you sure about this? So you want a query that will: Display a wall correctly, but only show posts that the user is allowed to see based on what the poster specified in access...

Comment: On the contrary, less table. Because if a user have 100 friends, as you said, it requires 100 different rows. But in json data format, for one user it requires one row. Anyway it do not matter. Could you help me to code sql query which will solve my problem?

Comment: Well..isn't that what tables are for? To have rows? Your storing your data as a String which is eating more data, than having a many to many table with 2 foreign keys (Integers) -> (user_id, friend_id) .
Storing this as a string makes both processing more slow, but also eats more data as Numbers as Characters eat more data. Anyway, posted an answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786918/many-to-many-relationship-use-associative-table-or-delimited-values-in-a-column which is exactly what we are discussing. A JSON array is essentialy a delimited list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If friends must be stored using JSON array something like the below could work.
I'm using like to search through your JSON string of friends.

```
select * from 
wall w,  
friends f
where 
w.poster_id = f.user_id and
(
    access = "all" or
    (
    f.friends like '[LOGGED_IN_USER_ID%' or
    f.friends like '%,LOGGED_IN_USER_ID,%' or
    f.friends like '%LOGGED_IN_USER_ID]'
    )
)
and
f.user_d = w.owner_id and
w.owner_id = WALL_OWNER_ID
```

Two inputs are:

- LOGGED_IN_USER_ID
- WALL_OWNER_ID

However, as posted in my comments, I think for friends a many to many table using 2 foreign key integers -> (user_id, friend_id) would be better.

- friend_id would reference users.user_id
- user_id would reference users.user_id

Would be for the following reasons:

1. No need to perform string searching.
2. No limit on number of friends based on varchar friends field size.
3. Encoding numeric data (ids) as strings, consumes more memory than encoding as integer.
4. Queries are much simpler with a many to many table.

See: [Many-to-many relationship: use associative table or delimited values in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786918/many-to-many-relationship-use-associative-table-or-delimited-values-in-a-column) for a similar discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I am at work. As soon as, I wil try it. With your help I believe that I will solve the problem.