# Many-to-many relationship database, which to pick with a lot of users

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

We are currently working on a game with a database where the player can have certain items who are stored in the database. I always learned at school and on the field to use option 1 but my colleague is saying option 2.

We have to pick one options and we are asking the question now: Which of the two options is the best and fastest?

And also which one is the best and fastest with 50K users?

[image: Table info]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many-to-many relationship: use associative table or delimited values in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786918/many-to-many-relationship-use-associative-table-or-delimited-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. You are correct.

If you use option 2 you'll be sorry. It's *denormalized*. Updating those comma-separated lists of itemID values is ridiculously difficult. You'll have to use transactions to read the value string, change it, and write it back.

Also, option 1 can exploit database indexes for much more efficient searching.  Ask your friend how you will find all users with itemId = 15. Ask him to write  that query for you.  With Option 1 you can use

```
  SELECT UserId
    FROM tbl
   WHERE ItemId = 15
```

You can use a query to generate option 2 for display. Display is all it's good for.

```
     SELECT UserId, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ItemId ORDER BY ItemID) ItemId
       FROM linktable
      GROUP BY UserId
```